# Firestore Query in Functions returning different snapshot each time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use an http request in a Firesbase function to query through a collection. I'm using Postman to hit this endpoint, and every time I run it, it's returning a different number of results within the snapshot.

I suspect this is an async issue where maybe the snapshot isn't fully returned by the time I'm console logging it. But, I'm struggling to figure out how since it's already in a promise. I'm probably doing something stupid (I'm still pretty new with promises), but can't seem to track this one down. What gives?

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.quoteReport = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var collectionRef = db.collection("quotes");
  var query = collectionRef
    .where("userRegion", "==", "South")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.size);
      return snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data().userName);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(200).send("Complete");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });
});
```

Comment: There are no partial or incomplete snapshots with Firestore.  If `snapshot.size` is changing with each query, then I would assume that value has to be correct.  Since we can't see your data and what else you might be doing with it, there's not much else that can be said here.

Comment: Is `console.log(snapshot.size);`giving a different/wrong result OR it is the `console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data().userName);`?

Comment: Both console.logs will return the same snapshot each query. Sometimes the snapshot is correct, sometimes it's wrong. I can hit the endpoint and it will return 70 records, I hit it a minute later and it returns 68, I hit it a minute later and it returns 60, then 70 again and so on... There isn't a pattern I can find for why it's returning different snapshots and it will sometimes return the same snapshot multiple times in a row. I'm 100% certain that the data isn't changing in Firestore between the queries, can't seem to track this one down.